# Can I use a variable to determine a string in a list?

Tags: python, list

I was going through some code when I tried to use an inputted variable to determine a certain string in a list. I have already used a lot of input separation to make it into 2 strings, and I cannot see what is wrong with my code.

I've tried to use a piece of code on my main project, but it glitched.

I've tried using this code on my main project:

```py
equipped = []
bag = ['foo', 'bar']
act = input()
if "Equip" or "equip" in act:
    inputPieces = act.split(' ')
    base = inputPieces[0]
    argument = inputPieces[1]
    slotnumber = int(argument) - 1
    item_equip = bag[slotnumber]
    equipped.append(item_equip)
```

and when I try to input `equip 1`it was supposed to add 'foo' to equipped, but it sends an error message that says

```py
argument = inputPieces[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It was expected to take the second part of my input (1) and append the respective string from "bag" to "equipped". But when I try to do so, the error message says (I think) that this part doesn't exist, so it cannot take the index.

Comment: Any chance the users enters a single word into ```act```?

Comment: basically your code depends on user input being splittable by space, surround it by a try/catch IndexError and handle the error properly. This would only happen when the string doesn't contains spaces

Comment: Well, it does contain spaces. I always put "equip 1", with a space, so I have no idea why it won't work. To extend a bit, it glitches when I try to use another command, but the line it shows that is the error is the one I've shown you. Maybe, somehow when I try the other command ```equipped``` it may have triggered what you have said, that it doesn't detect the other thing.

Comment: Also that `elif` seems an error to me, it would be better if you a show valid code

Comment: `elif "Equip" or "equip" in act:` That's not the right way to test for multiple values.  That if statement will _always_ be true.

Comment: Please add `print(act)` and `print(inputPieces)` to your code to confirm, visually, that your code is doing what you think it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have splitted data using space(act.split(' ')) that makes a list. List contains more than one data if the user input have space with user input. If user input contains only a single word having no space like just "equipefgfgh" then inputPieces[1] wont exist. In that case you will get the error stated in the question. so you have to check before access:

```
 if len(inputPieces) >1
```

or you can use try/except:

```
equipped = []
bag = ['foo', 'bar']
act = input()
if "Equip" in act or "equip" in act:
    try:
        inputPieces = act.split(' ')
        base = inputPieces[0]
        argument = inputPieces[1]
        slotnumber = int(argument) - 1
        item_equip = bag[slotnumber]
        equipped.append(item_equip)
    except:
        print("error occured")
```